# Importing singed C# dll into C++ project?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com-interop, gac

I'm trying to import .net dll into C++ project.
c++ code constains following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "RemoteAgentLibs.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
int main() {
    HRESULT init = CoInitialize( NULL );
    if (init != S_OK) return 1;

    ImportedNamespace::_ClassNamePtr myclass;
    myclass = new ImportedNamespace::_ClassNamePtr("ImportedNamespace.ClassName");
    myclass->MyMeyhod();
}
```

Everything works fine untill I check the "Sign the assembly" in properties of my .NET project.
In .NET project I get warning:

> Warning   3 "path to dll" does not contain any types that can be unregistered for COM Interop.
>
> Warning   3 "path to dll" does not contain any types that can be registered for COM Interop.

In C++ project I get error:

> error C2039: 'MyMethod' : is not a member of 'ImportedNamespace::_ClassNamePtr'

Could somebody tell me why there is a problme with importing strong name signed dlls?
or is there any other way to import my dll into c++ project and add dll to GAC

Comment: Is your C++ project strong-name signed?  Usually they both have to be.

Comment: I think it is, for my c++ project in properties->Cofiguration Properties->Linker->Advanced->KeyFile I have path to same file I'm using to sign .net project

Answer (score 0):

Did you look [SWIG](http://www.swig.org)? I think it's a good solution you just have to write a wrapper for your need...